# Docker build project from Docker Hub

Tags: docker, volume, dockerfile, dockerhub

I'd like to set up OpenProject using Docker. There are several decent options in the Hub, but so far I've tried [this one](https://hub.docker.com/r/abevoelker/openproject/) as the best possible option. I'd like to clone it, change the database default password (because I find it unsafe) and then build it and run it. How should I proceed?

I've tried `docker build -t myrepo/openproject dockerfile_location`. Then I get an error that git does not exist. I know that I could add `RUN apt-get install git`, but afterwards I encounter an error `checking for pg_config... no`. In order to fix that, I need to install postgres, but this means that I have to put the code and data in the same container. This is the situation that I'm trying to avoid.

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: I don't really follow. Why don't you check out the linked github repo and start there? https://github.com/abevoelker/docker-openproject

Comment: I'm doing it. After cloning I edit the appropriate script. I have a question, how to go on from there, because I get the errors described in the post.

Comment: Ok. I guess the base image has changed since the open project one was built and things have broken. If you want it fixed, it might be easiest to contact the author.

Comment: Ok, perfect. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to put the postgres binaries and data in the same container.  pg_config is basically configuring your postgres.

`pg_config` is in `postgresql-devel` (`libpq-dev` in Debian/Ubuntu)

In essence:

```
# container were your data is
docker run -d --name openproject-postgres-data -v /data busybox true
# container were postgres runs
docker run -d --name openproject-postgres --volumes-from openproject-postgres-data -e USER=super -e PASS=password paintedfox/postgresql
# container that actually runs your application and links to your db container
docker run -d --name openproject --link openproject-postgres:postgres -p 8080:80 abevoelker/openproject
```